# Call to calloc fails on 64 Bit system for arrays which are greater than 4GiB

Tags: c, linux, segmentation-fault, 64-bit, calloc

Note: I am new to learning C and this might have a completely easy solution which I am ignorant of. In that case, please enlighten me SO.

I am having issues debugging a C program, which I received from a colleague. In essence, I managed to trace the segfault error to a failing call to `calloc()` if `n` is bigger than 46341:

`float *v = (float*) calloc(n * (n - 1)/2, sizeof(float));`

Here is set of minimal code that triggers the problem:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]){

    int ngenes = 46341;

    float *v = (float*) calloc(ngenes * (ngenes - 1)/2, sizeof(float));
    if(v) printf("Allocation succeeded\n");
    free(v);

    ngenes++;

    v = (float*) calloc(ngenes * (ngenes - 1)/2, sizeof(float));
    if(v) printf("Allocation succeeded\n");
    free(v);

    return 0;
}
```

Same code on [ideone](http://ideone.com/6hA7g9).

AFAIK, this evaluates to exactly 4GiB, which is why I am suspicious. The systems I've tried this on are all 64bit, so the allocation shouldn't be a problem. Searching around on SO has brought up the idea that `calloc()` might be failing to find a contiguous space, so I tried several calls to `calloc()`, and also tried to call `realloc()`. Finally, I tried to implement the allocation n C++ with calls to `float *v = new float[n * (n - 1)/2]()` which throws a `bad_alloc` error.

The system I've been trying this on:

```
$ uname -a
Linux picea 3.13.0-35-generic #62-Ubuntu SMP Fri Aug 15 01:58:42 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

```
$ free
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:     396222336  368621612   27600724      32320     281536  346677332
-/+ buffers/cache:   21662744  374559592
Swap:    125061116   64894524   60166592
```

I have tried compiling with:

`gcc -m64 ...`

to no avail. Running `printf("%lu\n",SIZE_MAX);` returns `18446744073709551615`

Honestly, I am out of ideas.

Comment: `ngenes` is an `int`. How far can it count?

Comment: In C, you should write `float *v = calloc(n * (n - 1)/2, sizeof(*v));` C is not C++.

Comment: @BoPersson Thanks, yeah. I thought I had visited this possibility and I copied the code from my colleagues source file. Seems I thought wrong and that was exactly the issue. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're most likely compiling this on an LP64 architecture, where `int` is 32-bit, but `long` and pointers are 64-bit. The size calculation ends up being done at integer precision, *then* promoted to 64-bit, thus yielding incorrect size (negative, or much shorter than intended).

Solution is to use

```
size_t ngenes = 46341;
```

instead. `size_t` is the type you should use for sizes and lengths of in-memory objects.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I swear I had tried this already, but after your suggestion I tried to verify it and it's working. I blame the 4th glass of red wine.